# a simple way to read configuration properties

Tags: c++

I am trying to add few configurable properties to an existing code/project. I found it is really annoyance to have so many steps to do this:

1. add entry to the configuration file;
2. declare a key string in the h file;
3. define that key string in the cpp file;
4. declare a getXXX method/function in the h file;
5. define that getXXX method/function in the cpp file;

In our case, that header file and cpp file are only for properties read from text file and those properties are only needed inside this module. So we may be able to simplify them with less files or less steps. Any idea/suggestion?

**EDIT:**

A map is used to hold contents from the text file.

A sample get method likes this:

```
unsigned int Module1Config::getSleepTime()
{
    return getPropertyMap().getUnsignedIntProperty(SLEEP_TIME_KEY);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample? It's not clear to me why you would need `getX` method.

Comment: Any reason you can't just read them all into a `std::map`?

Answer (score 0):

What about a private `std::map` whose keys are just those declared in the configuration file. Then, you can have a getter function that gets the value typed as you need it, with a default value if it does not exist:

```
template<class T>
T get(const std::string &key) const
{
  if the key is in the map,
    return its value converted to type T
  else
    return T();
}
```

You may find useful a second function to tells you if some key is declared:

```
bool exists(const std::string &key) const
{
  return true iif key is in the map
}
```

The pros of this approach is that you don't need to modify the class when new properties are added. The con is that key names are not created as constant identifiers in your h file, so you have to use strings all the time, which may be error prone. Anyway, I think its versatility is worth it (this is the method I use in my programs).